# How to display data in flask custom admin template view

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I retrieve data from the database and want to show the data into the flask admin template. But the data can not be displayed in the admin template. Also, the admin route cant accept POST REQUEST.
How can I fix this problem?

**Here is route.py**

```
@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
        
    students = Student.query.all()
    
    return render_template('admin/index.html', title='Home', students=students)
```

**Below is index.html**

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
    
 {% block content %} 
    
   <div id="std-box">
      <h1> {{ students|length }} </h1>
      <a href="{{ url_for('student_Detials') }}"><h2>Total Students</h2></a>

      {% for std in students %}
      <p>std.std_name</p>
      {% endfor %}
           
   </div>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: I would look at the documentation. I am fairly new to Flask Admin although i dont think you need ```@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])```

Comment: Normally you just create model view